# Haskell: Non-exhaustive patterns in function. No idea why

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and I'm trying to implement the luhn algorithm.

I've created a helper function:

```
myMap :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
myMap p q [] = []
myMap p q [x] = [p x]
myMap p q (x : y : xs) = p x : q y : myMap p q xs
```

This function works fine. If I try to run it as `myMap (*2) (+0) [1,2,3,4]` it returns `[2,2,6,4]` which is the expected result.

Than I'm trying to implement the luhn algorithm:

```
luhn :: [Int] -> [Int]
luhn [x] = myMap (*2) (+0) [x]
```

This is part of the algorithm, I'll change it to return a `Bool`, but I'm trying to run as this is and it gives me:

> *** Exception: main.hs:92:1-30: Non-exhaustive patterns in function luhn

Why is this happening?

Comment: did you mean for that to just apply to singleton lists? Or did you mean it to apply to all lists: ie. `luhn xs = myMap (*2) (+0) xs` Which in turn can be simplified as `luhn = myMap (*2) (+0)` (and I would prefer to write `id` instead of `(+0)`, but that makes no difference).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody, really dumb mistake.

```
luhn :: [Int] -> [Int]
luhn x = myMap (*2) (+0) x
```

This was the correct form to implement the function. I don't know why I put `luhn [x] = myMap (*2) (+0) [x]`.

This way it's working now.

Comment: Not sure it's the mistake you made, but a common misunderstanding is that the pattern `[x]` would match a list (as opposed to some other type of value) and bind it to `x`, rather than match a list containing a single element.

Answer (score 0):

What would `luhn []` be, for example?

Your function is currently defined for a list of *one element*. What about other lists?

It can be:

```
luhn [x] = your code
luhn whatever_else = error "That's an error!"
```